# ASP.NET - SimpleMembershipProvider initialized incorrectly, how do I reinitialize it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, initialization

I have added the SimpleMemebershipProvider to my project, but have initialized the wrong fields in my database using `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "userId", "username", autoCreateTables: true);` Now, I've changed the parameters and tried to re-run it, but of course I receive the error "`WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection method can be called only once`"

I've deleted my entire database and tried to reinitialize the SMP, but it still seems to be aware that it's already been called. How can I reinitialize the SMP from scratch without making a new project?

By the way, if these parameters are allowed to be changed on the fly, what is causing me to receive the error "`An account with that username has already been created`" when attempting to register any username on the registration page?

Comment: Try to kill the ASP.NET IIS Server used during debugging or even close Visual Studio. Make sure the database does not exist looking through Server Explorer window inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Re-adding the Model.edmx resolved the issue, but I'm getting an error trying to register a user - the same issue as before infact! "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name."