# WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection on session start or request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I've got an application that I'm trying to convert from a uni-tenant (single client, separate database, separate website) solution, to a partially multi-tenant one (single client, separate database, SHARED website).

I'm trying to figure out how to get my simplemembership setup to work in a situation where I can't have `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` associated with Application_Start.   Instead, I want each session to setup its own 'web security context', independent of the application.  The reason I need this behavior, is that my user/membership data is held in the uni-tenant (separate database) portion of the system, and, if initialized at app_start, only allows access to the FIRST tenant to visit the app.  If I could, instead, make the websecurity system work within the session (or request) scope, this issue could be resolved.

I've been unable to find any documentation that says what I'm trying to do CAN NOT be done, but the indication is there all the same (In terms of lots of example posts saying that `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` should happen on app_start.

Short of completing the FULL transition to a multitenant database (which is on the schedule, but can't be completed in the allotted time), what can I do to workaround this 'limitation' ?

(my best idea so far, is that all client websites on a single website node (or better yet, across ALL nodes) would have to share a special login database)

### Edit

#### 2015-04-17

I found this post ([ASP.NET - SimpleMembershipProvider initialized incorrectly, how do I reinitialize it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885161)) which, though not being definitive, suggests that once the WebSecurity database is 'wired up', there is no facility for re-initializing later on.